# OpenCV, C++, VideoCapture error "...because opencv_videoio440d.dll was not found..."

Tags: c++, opencv, python

This works fine

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
```

This is the code that's not working

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        return -1;
    }
```

Here is the screenshot showing both the SystemError and another showing that the file `opencv_videoio440d.dll` exists

[file browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hg8V.jpg)

[SystemError screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9VAP.jpg)

if it helps;
These are the videos I followed to install OpenCV..

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5EWlNQ6z5w [PART 1]`

and

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-6rG6Zgu4U [PART 2]`

Comment: The error message told you exactly the problem. Also if this is a production application make sure you build the release version instead of the debug version.

Comment: ***opencv_videoio440d.dll exists*** I bet it is not in the same folder as the executable or in any of the folders that are listed in your OS `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: This will show you how to add entries to the `PATH` environment variable: [https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) after you make the change you may want to logout then login to ensure it is active in whatever IDE you are using.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for the reply, my system environment has path `C:\Open CV\x64\vc16\bin` which is where the files are. is this not correct?

Comment: You probably should not have added a space between Open and CV. That may cause a problem.

Comment: @drescherjm hi thanks very much, i just noticed i had incorrectly set the system path. thanks for the help!

Comment: Great, I still want to leave by giving you one piece of advice I have learned over my 30+ years of experience. In `c` or `c++` development it's best to avoid ever typing a space in any part of a path, folder or filename even in 2020 this still causes problems. One reason is the compiler usually is a command line utility spawned by an IDE or build tool.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add OpenCV binaries to your PATH? There is usually an option to "Add OpenCV to the system PATH for current user" when installing.

If not, you can add it as described here: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windowssetpathandenviromentvariable

Comment: hi! i was just notified my sys path was set incorrectly and the problem is now resolved! thank you very much for your comment though!